# Cant save data when engine is InnoDB but successful when MyISAM

Tags: php, mysql

Im developing PHP application with MySQL backend and there is an unfortunate event that I cant save data in MySQL from a PHP script. Theres no error or whatever but when I tried to insert data directly using phpmyadmin, the data was saved. When I checked the database engine..it said **InnoDB**...Something in my mind tells me to change it to **MyISAM** and when I did...it worked. I tried to google what happened but no luck. Can somebody explain what happened. Im using PDO in that matter.

```
require("path/to/connection.php");
//sample userid
$userid = 10;

try{
   $conn->beginTransaction();
   $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable(userid) VALUES(:userid)");
   $query->bindParam(":userid",$userid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $query->execute();
}catch(PDOException $e){
   $conn->rollBack();
   echo $e;
}
```

Comment: do you have some code? what your tables look like? do you know what are  differences between InnoDB and MyIsam?

Comment: You have to [commit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php) the transaction.  MyISAM doesn't support transactions but InnoDB does.  And there's really no reason to start a transaction when you only have one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting a transaction but never committing it. Since MyISAM doesn't support transactions it doesn't matter that you don't commit, but InnoDB won't write the data back until you do.

You need to do this:

```
try{
   $conn->beginTransaction();
   $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable(userid) VALUES(:userid)");
   $query->bindParam(":userid",$userid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $query->execute();
   $conn->commit();

}catch(PDOException $e){
   $conn->rollBack();
   echo $e;
}
```

For a single `INSERT` statement it makes no sense to use transactions, so you could do this:

```
try{
   $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable(userid) VALUES(:userid)");
   $query->bindParam(":userid",$userid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $query->execute();
}catch(PDOException $e){
   $conn->rollBack();
   echo $e;
}
```